# My low beams don’t turn on when I try to turn them on, but when I turn on my high beams the low beams turn on as well. 2003 Honda Accord

Tags: honda, accord, headlight

I checked all my fuses inside the car and under the hood with a multimeter, and they seem to all be good. What could be the problem here? My working theory is that there’s either some sort of wiring issue or I missed a fuse. I’ve never seen this problem before so I’m open to ideas.

Comment: When the high and low beams are both on, do they look like they are all working on full brightness?

Comment: They looked to be at full brightness yes

Answer (score 0):

The headlight relay may be malfunctioning. Look for it in the under hood fuse / relay box. Easy fix and inexpensive.

If the relay is not malfunctioning, then most likely the headlight switch in your steering column (controlled by the turn signal stalk) is worn out and malfunctioning.

Note that if you operate the headlights with both high and low filaments burning, the bulb can overheat and it could melt the headlight socket.

If the switch in the steering column must be repaired, this might be best left to a professional; the airbag can kill you. If you decide to tackle this yourself, **disconnect the battery**, then follow step by step instructions. It would be worthwhile to take a short subscription to an auto repair data service to get proper instructions for repair.

Comment: It ended up being a problem with the relays!